# Keep user-defined functions in global environment, during removal of objects

Tags: r

**Question:** How can I control the deletion (and saving) of user-defined function?

**What I have tried so far:**

I've gotten a recommendation to ad a dot [.] in the beginning of every function, being told that the functions would not be deleted. When tested, the function are deleted despite of staring with dot.

**Requirements:**

- All "non-function" should be handled by the [rm].
- Due to automation, the procedure needs to be able to be triggered by R base from a terminal. It is not enough that solution works only in Rstudio.
- Global environment to be used, due to keeping the solution standardized.
- If possible, one should be able to define which function to keep/delete.

**Expected outcome:**

- None of the functions in the example should be deleted.

Below you fin the example code:

```
# Create 3 object variables.
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3

# Create 3 functions.
myFunction1 <- function() {}
myFunction2 <- function() {}
myFunction3 <- function() {}

# Remove all from global.env.
# Keep the ones specified below.
rm(list = ls()[! ls() %in% c(
  "a",
  "c"
)
]
)
```

Comment: You could try creating another script that houses the functions and just source this at the top of your script?

Comment: Another option would be to define all of these functions in a separate project and then use `devtools::load_all()` on startup to simulate the functions being loaded as a package so they can not be removed and should always be available?

Comment: @Tom Yes, I am moving towards more functions, thus creating a centralized [functions.R] file. At the moment, though I source some R-files containing functions. Just posted the question for curiosity if it is possible to control at the level of [rm function].

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about that but it sounds like if you are creating a library of functions then moving down the `devtools::load_all()` route could be helpful.

Comment: @Tom Actually the problem is that if I load all my (user-defined functions) from a [function.R] say by having the loading from [.Rprofile], The mentioned [rm] commands would deleted those functions.

Comment: So what is your expected output? Which variables and functions should remain in the environment?

Comment: @Ronak I updated the question, with "expected outcome". - Also, cleaned up the text of question.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained myself well. If you create a project (e.g. "myfuncs") and place your function.R file within this, you can then use `devtools::load_all()` to mimic this project being loaded as a package much like `library()`. Your functions won't appear in your global.env but will be accessible from anywhere and can not be removed with any `rm()` command.

Comment: Your requirement "Global environment to be used, due to keeping the solution standardized." is nonsense. It is bad practice to use the global environment due to reasons you have partially discovered here.

Comment: Seems one approach could be to store all functions in a list and add that specifc to the [rm].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend a different approach. Don’t partially remove objects, use proper scope instead. That is, don’t define objects in the global environment that don’t need to be defined there, define them inside functions or `local` scopes instead.

Going one step further, your `functions.r` file *also* shouldn’t define functions in the global environment. Instead, as suggested in a comment, it should define them inside a dedicated environment which you may `attach`, if convenient. This is in fact what R packages solve. If you feel that R packages are too heavy for your purpose, I suggest you write modules using my ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/)’ package: it cleanly implements file-based code modules.

If you use scoping as it was designed, there’s no need to call `rm` on temporary variables, and hence your problem won’t arise.

If you *really* want a clean slate, restart R and re-execute your script: this is the only way to consistently reset the state of the R session; all other ways are error-prone hacks because they only perform a partial cleanup.

---

A note on what you wrote:

> When tested, the function are deleted despite of staring with dot.

They’re not — they’re just *invisible*; that’s what the leading dot does. However, this recommendation also strikes me as bad practice: it’s an unnecessary hack.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ls.str` to specify a `mode` of object to find. With this you can exclude functions from the `rm` list.

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(),ls.str(mode="function")))
ls()
[1] "myFunction1" "myFunction2" "myFunction3"
```

However, you might be better off formalising your functions in a package and then you would not need to worry about deleting them with `rm`.

Comment: This suggestion also deleted the object that are not functions.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Don't use the global environment.

```
myenv <- new.env()

with(myenv,
       {
         # Create 3 object variables.
         a <- 1
         b <- 2
         c <- 3
       }
       )
myenv$a
#[1] 1

# Create 3 functions.
myFunction1 <- function() {}
myFunction2 <- function() {}
myFunction3 <- function() {}

# Remove all from env.
# Keep the ones specified below.
rm(list = ls(envir = myenv)[! ls(envir = myenv) %in% c(
  "a",
  "c"
)
], envir = myenv
)

ls(envir = myenv)
#[1] "a" "c"
```